# Offset function in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following code:

```
ord_reg<- clm(as.factor(y)~log10(x), data=dataframe, link="probit")
```

Suppose that I want to specify that the probit slope is 1.2. Would this be the correct code:

```
ord_reg<- clm(as.factor(y)~log10(x)+offset(probit_slope=1.2), data=dataframe, link="probit")
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the name of the variable for which you want to fix a parameter? Let's pretend it is `x2` and you want to fix the parameter to `1.2`

```
ord_reg<- clm(as.factor(y)~log10(x)+offset(x2*1.2), data=dataframe, link="probit")
```

Ben Bolker suggested you want the log10(x) parameter fixed. In which case, you'd do the following:

```
ord_reg<- clm(as.factor(y)~offset(log10(x)*1.2), data=dataframe, link="probit")
```

Comment: I think the OP might want `as.factor(y)~offset(1.2*log10(x))` ?